# PHP/MySQL Search - the next step from MATCH AGAINST

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, memcached

I currently have a `(MATCH column) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` search. It's okay, a little slower than I'd like it to be but I'm joining a few tables and filtering data which reduces its performance.

What would be the step up from this? Is it possible to cache data in MySQL or using Memcached so it can be accessed faster?

Comment: You might like a presentation I did comparing different solutions: [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql) or the video recording: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Sa7TvXnQwY

Comment: How many rows in the tables?  Let's see the desired `JOINs`.